# Service restart long time

Tags: android

I have a service to using BroadcastReceiver to monitor several action (Screen on/off and Wifi on/off) and a schedule task.  My service so far is OK.  I know service will be auto restarted when system has low resource that it is OK for me but I have face on a problem that sometime my service always state in "Restarting Service" long time over 1 hours.  When I restart the service manually, the service can run smoothly.  I don't know what problem exist.

Comment: It's hard to be able to tell anything without you posting a little bit of code.  Don't post the whole thing, but try to post enough to show what is happening.

Comment: I found out what problem exist that the behavior is different from 2.3.x and 4.0.